# Appium different caps for different test

Tags: python, cucumber, bdd, appium-android, desiredcapabilities

I'm using Python Behave `BDD` tests. I have written multiple tests and only one test requires `fullReset` set to false, `noReset` set to true and different `appWaitActivity` than other tests. Is there some way to make in the `device.py` file for the test to recognize this test and then set those desired caps? Like with if scenario name is "that" then allow those caps, any advice is helpful.

My question is if it is possible to retrieve `Cucumber` Scenario name in `Python` code which runs this test?

Comment: I see this is your first question. Keep in mind this: "Questions are supposed to include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)". Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53633938/edit) your question and add more info?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I edited my question. But if somebody has been using Python Behave I presume he will understand what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one possible solution. You can put

```
import sys
```

and later you can add

```
if sys.argv[1] == name_needed_test:
```

In this if clause you can put desired capabilities you need.